# Use postgresql copy command On Openshift $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR from within Node JS program

Tags: postgresql, upload, openshift

we are developing an app on Openshift.
we recently upgraded it and made it scalable, separating postgresql to a separate gear than the nodeJS.

in the app user can choose a csv file and upload it to the server (`$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`).
we then execute from within Node JS:

```
copy uploaded_data FROM '/var/lib/openshift/our_app_id/app-root/data/uploads/table.csv' WITH CSV HEADER
```

since the upgrade the above `copy` command is broken, we are getting this error:

```
[error: could not open file "/var/lib/openshift/our_app_id/app-root/data/uploads/table.csv" for reading: No such file or directory]
```

I suppose because the pgsql is now on a separate gear it cannot access `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`.

1. can I make this folder visible to postgresql (though it is on a separate gear)?
2. is there any other folder that can be visible to both the DB and the APP (each on its own gear) ?
3. can you suggest alternative ways to achieve similar functionality ?

Comment: what we're finally doing is read the csv file into the node application, parse it and create tables and insert records.

Comment: I guess that from the same reason we can't execute pg_dump when connecting through SSH to the scalable openshift app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no shared disk space between gears within the same scaled application on OpenShift Online.  If you want to store a file and access it on multiple gears, the best way would probably be to store it on Amazon S3 or some other shared file storage service that is accessible by all of your gears, or, as you have stated, store the data in the database and access it wherever you need it.

Comment: thank you @corey I figured this is the situation. The problem was uploading the data into the database, with pgsql COPY command. but finally we're executing CREATE and INSERT from the application which does see $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can do this by using \COPY and psql. e.g.
first put your sql command in a file. (file.sql)
psql -h yourremotehost -d yourdatabase -p thedbport -U username -w -f  file.sql   

the -w eliminates the password prompt.  If you need a password, you can't   supply it on the command line.  Instead set the environmental variable    PGPASSWORD to your password.  (The use of PGPASSWORD has been deprecated but it still works)
You can do this with rhc

rhc set-env PGPASSWORD=yourpassword -a yourapp
```

Here is a sample sql

```
CREATE TABLE junk(id integer, values float, name varchar(100);
\COPY junk from 'file.sql' with CSV HEADER
```

Notice there is NO semicolon at the end of the second line.

If you're running this command from a script in your application.  The file that contains your data and the file.sql must be in your application's data directory.

```
ie. app-root/data
```

Comment: I have fixed the sql above \COPY instead of /COPY

Comment: app-root/data which is visible to the script is not visible to postgresql in a scalable app, in that case script and pgsql live in separate gears and cannot see each other's file system.